# Why Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql connecting twice causing transaction fail?

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, transactions

I am running some queries inside transaction but weirdly Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql is connecting to mysql server twice inside the transaction causing implicit rollback on transaction causing "No active transaction" error.

Here's my profiler output.
[image]
Please look at line number 7 where the another "connect" function running. Which causes implicit rollback on transaction .

[image]
This is now successfully working after I move the "begin transaction" just below "SELECT MEETING" query in line number 6.

Could not understand how this happens?

I am using Zend Framework 1.12.20.

Comment: Any errors/exceptions logged? Can you run this sql directly inside mysql? May be apostrophe problem?

Comment: I haven't tried running directly on mysql. This is the profiler report of zend framework.